# How to run go generate only for changed templates?

Tags: go, generated-code

We use some code templates in our repo, and we rely on `go:generate` to generate all the needed codes from these templates.
Because there are several templates and from each template we generate several actual codes, consistency of generated codes has become an issue: we needed a command to run and be sure that all generated codes are up to date with their corresponding templates. To do this, we have a simple bash command that find all files that have `go:generate` in them, and runs `go generate` in their directory.
The problem is that this approach is really slow: most of the templates have not changed, so there is no need to generate their codes again.
Is there any way to tell `go generate` to only run if the template is newer than the file? Or, is there any better approach other than this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What kind of templates do you have? And what kind of code is generated?

Comment: it's a workaround for generics: the code that is being generated is valid & compilable go, and templates are go codes that have some variables that would be replaced with several struct names

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need that bash script that looks for `go:generate` in files, the `go` tool itself can do that for you. Just use

```
go generate ./...
```

to recurse in subfolders.

Next, when a code generation runs, I would store the template file's last modification timestamp in the generated code, either in a comment or in a const / var. The app that is run by `go generate` could first check if the template's last mod time is newer that the stored one in the code, and only proceed if so.

This file last mod time should be enough. But if for some reason you can't rely on it, the template could have a "version", which should be incremented when the template is changed. And have the generator "transfer" this version into the final code, which can be used to check if the template is newer than the code generated from it.

Comment: thanks for the first hint! about checking the timestamp or version, yes I know that this approach would work, but is there any switch or any ready tool that I can use? or should I write it myself?

Comment: @sazart None that I know of.

Comment: So reinvent the wheel instead of using makefiles?

Answer (score 0):

Check **go-generate-fast**, a drop in replacement to “go generate” that makes re-generations really fast. It caches the output when the inputs are the same, has support for multiple (a growing list of) tools, and supports custom scripts.

https://github.com/oNaiPs/go-generate-fast

Disclosure: I am the main developer.